# Cannot authenticate to api.github.com using app token

Tags: jwt, token, github-api

I am trying to follow the instructions here to identify as an app with JWT to api.github.com:

https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps/

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I always get "bad credentials".
Can anyone look at my code here and figure it out? (Node JS)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('doronsaartestapp.pem');
var token = jwt.sign(
    { 
      iat: new Date().getTime() / 1000,
      exp: new Date().getTime() / 1000 + 10*60,
      iss: 'Iv1.5a751653c88a7cd2'//84487
    }, 
    privateKey, 
    {algorithm: 'RS256'}
);
console.log('token: ' + token);

var http = require('https');
var options = {
  host: 'api.github.com',
  path: '/repos/doronsaar/panther-proxy/hooks',
  headers: { 
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw+json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36' 
  }
};

callback = function(response) {
    console.log("response status code: " + response.statusCode);
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
  });

  //the whole response has been received, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log("--end--");
  });
  
  
}


http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Comment: See if [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/apps/authenticating-with-github-apps) documentation helps.

Comment: It looks identical to the link I used...